# SDL TTF Library Memory Leaks (Creating and Freeing Surfaces Every Frame)

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-leaks, sdl, sdl-ttf

I am creating a basic SDL+OpenGL level editor for a game I'm making, and I'm encountering some pretty severe memory leaks when creating dynamic TTF surfaces, then converting them to OpenGL textures.

For example:

Every frame, I run some code that looks like this:

```
shape_label = SDL_DisplayFormat(TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, shape_names[c2].c_str(), textColor));
shape_label_gl = gl_texture(shape_label);
draw_rect(shapes[c2][0], shapes[c2][1], shape_label->w, shape_label->h, shape_label_gl, 0);
SDL_FreeSurface(shape_label);
```

However, when I use valgrind it suggests lots of relatively large memory leaks. When I monitor the program in Activity Monitor (Mac), it can climb to almost 500 mb of memory usage, and would probably continue from there.

Here's the valgrind error(s):

```
==61330== 1,193,304 (13,816 direct, 1,179,488 indirect) bytes in 157 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6,944 of 6,944
==61330==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==61330==    by 0x4D667: SDL_CreateRGBSurface (in /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL)
==61330==    by 0xE84C3: TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid (in /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf)
==61330==    by 0xE836D: TTF_RenderText_Solid (in /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf)
==61330==    by 0x10000A06D: SDL_main (in ./leveleditor)
==61330==    by 0x100013530: -[SDLMain applicationDidFinishLaunching:] (in ./leveleditor)
==61330==    by 0x65AD0D: __-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_1 (in /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation)
==61330==    by 0x36C7B9: _CFXNotificationPost (in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation)
==61330==    by 0x646FC2: -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation)
==61330==    by 0xB4C4E2: -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==61330==    by 0xB4C248: -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
==61330==    by 0xB4AF0F: -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] (in /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit)
```

Any ideas on how to make TTF work frame-to-frame without using huge amounts of memory?

**EDIT:** For future reference, I am a moron. I forgot to do this:

```
glDeleteTextures(1, &status_bottom_gl);
```

Answer (score 1):

TTF_RenderText_Solid allocates a new surface that you are not freeing:

```
SDL_Surface *ttf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, shape_names[c2].c_str(), textColor);
shape_label = SDL_DisplayFormat(ttf);
shape_label_gl = gl_texture(shape_label);
draw_rect(shapes[c2][0], shapes[c2][1], shape_label->w, shape_label->h, shape_label_gl, 0);
SDL_FreeSurface(shape_label);
SDL_FreeSurface(ttf); // Must free this as well!
```

Note that for optimal performance you should cache those surfaces somewhere and not create & destroy them every frame.

Comment: It still goes up when I do that... When I cout the opengl Gluint variable it goes up steadily every time. Is there a way to free opengl textures?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. Was forgetting `glDeleteTextures(1, &status_bottom_gl);` or the like.